# How to Fix Squarespace Code Injection To Re-Order Blog Posts Alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, content-management-system, squarespace

I Attempt to re-order blog posts alphabetically by their title on a Squarespace blog, rather than by their publication date.

https://www.flickr.com/photos/143173834@N03/40105624213/in/shares-5X84R2/

Helpful links:

Blog Excerpts https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813758

Code Injections https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815928-Adding-custom-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         if( $('.blog-list article').length != 0 ){
             var categories = []; 
             $('.blog-list article').each(function () {
               categories.push({
                 categoryName: $(this).find('.p-name a').html(),
                 listItem: $(this)
               });
             });
             categories.sort(function(a,b) {
               var c = a.categoryName.toUpperCase();
               var d = b.categoryName.toUpperCase();
               return (c > d) ? 1 : ((d > c) ? -1 : 0);
             });
             $.each(categories, function(index, object){
                 object.listItem.appendTo(object.listItem.parent());
             });
         }
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Apologies, @Roysh. Post has now been edited.

Comment: There are different ways to achieve this, but the complexity depends on a number of factors (not the least of which is that the 'list' page has a limit, and so will not take into account those posts that aren't on page 1). Can you provide a link to the page in question, or can you say what template you are using? Also, how many posts do you anticipate having (will it be a fixed number or will it grow over time and, if so, to about how many)? Are you attempting to sort by title or category?

Comment: @Brandon Thank you for your response - very much appreciated. I am using the Rally template. (I am open to changing the template if it were less complex with an alternative template). The number of posts will grow over time - a few per week. I am attempting to sort by title. Please do let me know if you need more information. Do you believe there is a work around for the 'list' page having a limit? Possibly an infinite scroll plug in?

Comment: @domburford - your code seem to do sort the categories by the `categoryName` property - what goes wrong exactly?

Comment: @Roysh at this moment in time, the code doesn't work in anyway; can't figure out which element needs to be re-worked. It's for categories but I'd like to manipulate it to work with the title instead of category. Many thanks.

Comment: the code that is in charge of sorting - does work!
Your problem might come from fetching the wrong element